# When submitting an ajax request, how can you "put the original request on hold" temporarily until a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am wanting to implement a recaptcha process that captures all ajax requests before they go through - the desired process would be as follows:

1. User completes an action which is going to cause an ajax request of some sort.
2. If the user has already completed the recaptcha process, the ajax request proceeds without further delay
3. If the user has not completed the recaptcha process, put the ajax request "on hold" temporarily until the recaptcha process is completed, then continue the ajax request.

I have got things to a state where I intercept the call, however I don't know how to put it on hold temporarily. Here's the relevant code:

```
<script>
    var captchaValidated = null;

    var currentRequests = [];
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        if (options.url != "/ValidateCaptcha") {
            if (captchaValidated == null || captchaValidated == false) {
                if (captchaValidated == null){
                    openRecaptcha();
                } else {
                    verifyCaptcha(); //see async question in method
                }
                if (!captchaValidated) {
                    jqXHR.abort();
                } else {
                    //let the original request proceed now - but how?!
                }
            }
        }
    });

    function verifyCaptcha() {
        var grecaptcha = $("g-recaptcha-response");
        var encodedResponse;
        if (grecaptcha != null) {
            encodedResponse = grecaptcha.val();
            $.ajax({
                async: false, //set to false so that the calling method completes rather than async - what do you think?
                headers: headers,
                cache: false,
                url: "/ValidateCaptcha",
                type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                //parse the data - did we get back true?
                captchaValidated = data;
            },
            error: function (raw, textStatus, errorThrown) { captchaValidated = null; alert("Validate ReCaptcha Error: " + JSON.stringify(raw)); },
            data: JSON.stringify({ "encodedResponse": encodedResponse })
            });
        }
    }

    function invalidateCaptcha(){
        captchaValidated = null;
    }
    function openRecaptcha() {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': "thekey",
            'callback': verifyCaptcha,
            'expired-callback': invalidateCaptcha,
            'type': 'audio image'
        });
        $("#recaptchaModal").modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

Any suggestions of how to proceed would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to store a future request at `verifyCaptcha`? If `grecaptcha != null` is `false`? When would `grecaptcha != null` be `null` if `grecaptcha` is a jQuery object `var grecaptcha = $("g-recaptcha-response");`? Is `g-recaptcha-response` element dynamically appended to `document`?

Comment: You can use a variable. Initially set it to false. When recaptcha is verified, set variable to true. Your other AJAX requests can be wrapped in an if/else that requires the variable to be true.

Comment: @guest271314 No, verifyCaptcha should only execute when captchaValidated == null. If it's false, it has already been considered a "don't" and any requests are aborted. If it's null, then the modal opens and the user tries again. If it's true, then the request should proceed without further delay.

Comment: @gibberish I'm hoping to leave the other ajax requests alone rather than wrapping them in an if/else so that this will become a globally overriding method that intercepts the calls.

Comment: _"No, verifyCaptcha should only execute when captchaValidated == null"_ That currently occrus, yes? What is expected result of `grecaptcha != null` ? Where `grecaptcha` is a jQuery object?

Comment: Interesting, I think to wait for some event in Ajax call you should use `jQuery.Deferred()`
See this answer that will helps you to understand 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39679275/6608101

Comment: @guest27134 correct - I believe the logic is in place to handle the cases of when to block the call, what is unclear is how to actually put the call on hold when the logic says "hold on, put them through the recaptcha process first then check to see if they should proceed or be blocked"

Comment: `grecaptcha != null` would not be `null` as you have passed a jQuery object to evaluate. Do you want to wait until `openCaptcha` is called again if `grecaptcha` element is not found in `document`?, then call `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @Loading thank you having a look

Comment: @guest271314 I understand what you're saying but that isn't really the hurdle - grecaptcha "should" always return an element, but I notice that what the code doesn't do is set captchaValidated = null after the jqXHR.abort() call in order to permit the user to try again if the server-side captcha check failed. The hurdle is putting an incoming ajax request "on hold"; the rest is just there for better understanding of the goal.

Comment: Where do you call `invalidateCaptcha` to set `captchaValidated = null` after `jqXHR.abort()` is called? If `grerepcaptcha` should always return an element what is purpose of `if` condition?  Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate issue?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Loading and @guest271314 for your help in pointing me in the right direction that helped me get things figured out. I've pasted how I accomplished it below - perhaps it will be of help to someone else. Of course if anyone would like to weigh in on my implementation please do.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCaptcha&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script>
<script>
    var captchaValidated = null;
    var currentRequests = [];
    var captchaPrompted = false;
    var captchaReady = false;
    var resetCaptcha = false;
    function onloadCaptcha() {
        captchaReady = true;
        captcha = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
            'sitekey': '<yoursitekey>',
            'callback': verifyCaptcha,
            'expired-callback': invalidateCaptcha,
            'type': 'audio image'
        });
    }

    var deferredCaptcha = null;
    var promiseCaptcha = null;
    var captcha = null;
    function openRecaptcha() {
        if (!captchaReady) {
            setTimeout(openRecaptcha, 50);
        }
        if (captchaPrompted) {
            return;
        }
        captchaPrompted = true;
        var captchaTimer = setInterval(function () {
            if (captchaValidated != null) {
                if (captchaValidated) {
                    deferredCaptcha.resolve();
                } else {
                    deferredCaptcha.reject();
                    captchaValidated = null;
                }
            }
        }, 100);
        if (resetCaptcha) {
            captcha.reset();
        }
        deferredCaptcha = $.Deferred();
        promiseCaptcha = deferredCaptcha.promise();
        promiseCaptcha.done(function () {
            //captcha was successful
            clearInterval(captchaTimer);
            //process the queue if there's items to go through
            if (currentRequests.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < currentRequests.length; i++) {
                    //re-request the item
                    $.ajax(currentRequests[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        promiseCaptcha.fail(function () {
            //captcha failed
            clearInterval(captchaTimer);
            currentRequests = []; //clear the queue
        });
        $("#recaptchaModal").modal('show');
    }

    function verifyCaptcha() {
        resetCaptcha = true;
        var response = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
        var encodedResponse;
        // confirm its validity at the server end 
        $.ajax({
            headers: headers,
            cache: false,
            url: "/ValidateCaptcha",
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                captchaValidated = data;
                if (!data) {
                    captchaPrompted = false;
                }
            },
            error: function (raw, textStatus, errorThrown) { captchaValidated = false; captchaPrompted = false; alert("WTF Validate ReCaptcha Error?!: " + JSON.stringify(raw)); },
            data: JSON.stringify({ "encodedResponse": response })
        });
    }
    function invalidateCaptcha(){
        deferredCaptcha.reject();
        captchaValidated = null;
        resetCaptcha = true;
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            if (settings.url == '/ValidateCaptcha' || captchaValidated) {
                // we're validating the captcha server side now or it's already been validated - let it through
            } else {
                if (typeof settings.nested === 'undefined'){
                    settings.nested = true; //this flag is to determine whether it's already in the queue
                    currentRequests.push(settings); //add the request to the queue to be resubmitted
                    //prompt them with the captcha
                    openRecaptcha();
                }
                return false; // cancel this request
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

At `$.ajaxPrefilter()` use `.then()` chained to `openCaptcha` to call `verifyCaptcha`

```
if (captchaValidated == null){
                openRecaptcha().then(verifyCaptcha);
            }
```

at `verifyCaptcha` use `.is()` with parameter `"*"` to check if an element exists in `document`

```
if (grecaptcha.is("*")) {
```

at `openRecaptcha()`, if `grecaptcha.render` does not return asynchronous result return jQuery promise object using `.promise()`; else chain to `grecaptcha.render` and `$("#recaptchaModal").modal('show')`; using `$.when()`

```
return $("#recaptchaModal").modal('show').promise()
```

or

```
return $.when(grecaptcha.render(/* parameters */)
       , $("#recaptchaModal").modal('show').promise())
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (pseudo-code)

```js
verified = false;

$('#myButton').click(function(){
  if (!verified) verify_by_captcha();
  if (verified){
    $.ajax(function(){
      type: 'post',
       url: 'path/to/ajax.php',
      data: your_data
    })
    .done(function(recd){
      //ajax completed, do what you need to do next
      alert(recd);
    });
  }
});//end myButton.click
```

Comment: thank you, I appreciate it however I am hoping to accomplish this without requiring modification of the existing methods that initiate or perform ajax requests hence harnessing ajaxPrefilter.